# Can't connect to home WiFi but can to phone hotspot

Tags: wireless

I have just installed the latest Ubuntu and I am having trouble connecting to my home WiFi(Starlink). I can connect to my phones hotspot. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching ON Bluetooth and switch Off
and try to connect the Home wifi.
if not connecting still, Switch the Air plane mode ON and then Off and then, try to scan the available wifi connections. You will be able to find in the list of wifi connections.
Now try to connect the Home wifi.
If not able to connect, then do forget connection for the wifi, and then try again scanning for available wifi and connecting to the wifi when displays in the list.
You will be able to connect now.
Thanks

Comment: I am using version 22.04